# Count the occurrence of a word in a txt file in python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose we don't need to bother with the upper case or lower case so I used re.IGNORECASE.

I have used the regular expression to solve this question. This is how I solved:

```
total = 0
for line in alllines:
    count = 0
    count = len(re.findall(word, line, re.IGNORECASE))
    total += count
```

But I meet a new question that I'd like to know. What if I only want the complete word? For example if the line contains 'helloworld' then if my term is 'hello', it should not be counted. But my way will count it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put word boundry `\bhello\b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match a complete word, you need to use word boundaries.

```
count = len(re.findall(r'\b'+ word + r'\b', line, re.IGNORECASE))
```

But this would match `hello` in `foo:hello:bar`. If you don't want this type of matching then you could use lookaround assertions to match an exact complete word.

```
count = len(re.findall(r'(?<!\S)'+ word + r'(?!\S)', line, re.IGNORECASE))
```

If the `word` you did like to pass in the regex contains specail chars then you need to apply the `re.escape` function on that word before using it inside the regex.

```
count = len(re.findall(r'(?<!\S)'+ re.escape(word) + r'(?!\S)', line, re.IGNORECASE))
```

`(?<!\S)` called negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceeded by a non-space character. Why we use assertions here means, it won't match any character but it asserts whether a match is possible or not. `(?!\S)` called negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a non-space character. ie, anything follows the match except a non-space character.

Comment: Thank you. I learn new knowledge today ^.^

Comment: I have a string 
    
    str = '"RT @5SOS":"multidaymuLt432@gmail.comi @add_df"'

And I write a regular expression to match those @... 

    match = r'@\w+'

    count = re.findall(match,'"RT @5SOS":"multidaymuLt432@gmail.comi @add_df"',re.IGNORECASE)
    print(count)
The output is below:

    ['@5SOS', '@gmail', '@add_df']

But I only want those @.. with a space before it. So the expected output is like:
    
    ['@5SOS', '@add_df']

I've tried match = r\s'@\w+' but the answer is quite different with the expected result because it goes like this.

    [' @5SOS', ' @add_df']
Any suggestions?

Comment: put `\s` inside a positive lookbehind like `r'(?<=\s)@\w+'` or use capturing group `r'\s(@\w+)'`

Comment: (?<=\s) what is that mean?

Comment: positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a space character.

Comment: depending on the definition of "word" and the allowed separators in the given use case,  you might consider replacing the white space character \s with the [word boundary](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) character \b